# How to center my dock icons in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: dock

Currently I've set the dock to bottom. I'd like to make the icons float in the center as compared to the default left alignment. I tried searching but most answers are for older Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Default dock? You can use `gsettings` commands that relates to dash-to-dock or install `dconf-editor` GUI tool and look for dash-to-dock options. ubuntu-dock  can be configured in the above way even though dash-to-dock extension is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Install the extension dconf-editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Open the dconf-editor, find the option extend-hight and mark to **False**